# Creating A Text Based Maze Generator In Python

Tags: python, text, random, graph, maze

I am a beginner in coding in general, but I know my way around the basics. as a challenge, and possibly a tool for map generation, I wanted to see if I could use python to create a small text based 5x5 maze generator that is isolated (no exits or entrances) that allows both loops and dead ends. I hand drew one as an example:

```
┌ → ↑ ┌ ┐

├ ─ ┴ ┼ ┤

│ ┌ ┬ ┘ │

├ ┘ │ ← ┤

↓ ← ┴ ─ ┘
```

(arrows represent dead ends coming from the opposite direction of the arrow)

I was unable to make much progress, and gave up rather quickly, deciding that my coding knowledge was not at the level to create something this complex. now I want to know if there is a simple way to do such a thing. after going down a rabbit hole of spanning trees, visual codes, and the such, 95% of which I barely understood, I couldn't find much to help me. I'm looking for a (hopefully) easy to understand way of creating a piece of code that could achieve this. Ideally I want the answer to be in python, and be something relatively easy to understand for a beginner-medium programmer given enough time. Also, please excuse any horribly vague/overly-complicated parts of this question I have written, they would most likely be due to the fact that I don't know much about this area of coding.

if there is a simpler way to phrase this question, or significantly easier methods of creating a 5x5 maze other than making it text based, these are also very welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

From http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation#Python, this should let you choose the size of the maze you want to create (it should make a 5x5).

It uses the text characters for walls rather than hallways but the general concepts should still be useful.

```
from random import shuffle, randrange

def make_maze(w = 16, h = 8):
    vis = [[0] * w + [1] for _ in range(h)] + [[1] * (w + 1)]
    ver = [["|  "] * w + ['|'] for _ in range(h)] + [[]]
    hor = [["+--"] * w + ['+'] for _ in range(h + 1)]

    def walk(x, y):
        vis[y][x] = 1

        d = [(x - 1, y), (x, y + 1), (x + 1, y), (x, y - 1)]
        shuffle(d)
        for (xx, yy) in d:
            if vis[yy][xx]: continue
            if xx == x: hor[max(y, yy)][x] = "+  "
            if yy == y: ver[y][max(x, xx)] = "   "
            walk(xx, yy)

    walk(randrange(w), randrange(h))
    for (a, b) in zip(hor, ver):
        print(''.join(a + ['\n'] + b))

make_maze()
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! while its really cool and exactly what im trying to make, im looking for more of an explanation than an example. i read through the code and most of the wiki page, and while most of it makes sense, im still a bit confused about how this code works. is there anywhere i can find an explanation on this piece of code?

Comment: @Jancl0: Did you read the very top of the [wiki page](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Maze_generation) which references this [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) and specifically the [Depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm#Depth-first_search) algorithm?